# Should I use interface builder or not?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I'd like to know more about the pros and cons of using interface builder when developing iPhone/iPad apps.

I've written a fairly complex and customized app that's on the app store right now, but all of the interfaces are hand coded as they are fairly complex. I've customised the navigation and tab bars with backgrounds, table view cells are manually drawn for speed, and some views are complex and scalable with many subviews.

I'm pondering whether or not to start using interface builder but I'm not sure to what extent I'll use it and whether it's worth it at all. Is it quicker? Can things still be easily customised?

Any advice would be most welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason not to use it.  One thing that scares people off is their experiences with other GUI tools, things that generated code for them or some other mess.  Then the problem becomes that it is hard to round-trip the interface, you cannot easily modify things once they are generated because of the complexity of pushing those changes back into the emitted code.

Interface Builder does not generate code, it uses NSArchiver to read and write an actual object graph for the GUI.  This has many benefits, starting with the fact that you can easily round-trip the interface and make incremental changes.  It really is all good, use it. :-)

Comment: If you had to dynamically generate your views, how would you take advantage of IB?

Comment: @pgpb.padilla Often you can compose the components you are using to build the view in IB and then instantiate them as you need for your dynamic generation.  One common example of this is a table where each row is an independent view that is generated on the fly. The smaller elements and be built in IB while the larger configuration is managed dynamically.  What sort of dynamic generation do you have in mind?

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, the scenario I'm thinking is this: suppose you consume a JSON service which has the UI specification: control identifier, type (date, input, label, etc). The number of controls is variable depending of the parameters passed to the service.

Comment: @pgpb.padilla It depends on the granularity of what you are doing, if you are making a generic canvas type element where anything can go anywhere then you might not have anything for IB to do.  But if you are doing something like rendering a set of objects with some common structure you can use IB for the common parts.  At the end of the day IB is just a graphic editor for the objects themselves (modulo serialization / deserialization) so all you are doing is moving effort back and forth between coding and a visual editor. Or a template system if it help to think of deserialization that way...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've found Interface Builder quite tricky to ramp up on, and sometimes it doesn't expose all the properties I want to edit (although this may have changed in the newer versions), so generally I've tended to create my UIs in code.

If you do use Interface Builder, make sure to consider localization.  Apple's [iPhone Developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html) recommend that the NIB be a localized resource that gets translated.  That way the translator can see if the new text fits in the view.  Unfortunately this means the translator needs to be capable of opening NIB files and editing them (or a developer needs to get involved in the translation process).

Personally, I prefer providing localized text resources and setting the text to the UI in code.  I then provide comments in the Localizable.strings file saying how long the text can be, and providing any context the translator might need.

Answer (score 0):

There are no cons.
Why dont use it? It makes everything easier :)